# Simplifying trivial expression

Tags: functions, logarithms

How to simplify an expression: $e^{\frac{-\ln^2 y}{2}}$? I mean because as if $e^{\ln y}=y$ then my guess is that this could be simplified in a similar manner thus how to do that?

Comment: $$\frac1{\sqrt{y^{\ln(y)}}}$$ if you consider this simpler.

Comment: appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write $e^{-\frac12 \log^2(y)}$ a number of different ways.  One way, we have

$$\begin{align}
e^{-\frac12 \log^2(y)}&=e^{\log(y)\log(y^{-1/2})}\\\\
&=e^{\log(y^{-1/2\log(y)})}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^{\log(y)}}}
\end{align}$$

A second way is to write

$$\begin{align}
e^{-\frac12 \log^2(y)}&=e^{\log(y)\log(y^{-1/2})}\\\\
&=e^{\log(y^{\log(y^{-1/2})})}\\\\
&=y^{\log(1/\sqrt y)}
\end{align}$$